# Jomsocial Working with registration form

Tags: php, joomla2.5, jomsocial

I am working on joomla 2.5 i have created a website in which i used the jomsocial component.By default on jomsocial user registration user clicks registraion and he will proceed to the jomsocial registration page. I want when the user clicks on the registration button he will proceed to the plans page (created by me) and after selecting the users plan users will be redirected to the default registration process page? How is that possible which files do i need to edit and how should i get the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you have to create your own plugin, or you have to buy that plugin from the jomsocial website. Here is a link to their website from where you can buy your `http://documentation.jomsocial.com/wiki/API_Eventsplugins`

Answer (score 0):

In that case you have to create a Jomsocial plugin & make the changes as you want, There are plenty of Jomsocial plugin events like onUserlogin OnBeforeFormSubmit etc.
http://documentation.jomsocial.com/wiki/API_Events